# Generating an API key in the ActiveCollab UI

Tags: activecollab

We have a self-hosted instance of ActiveCollab.  The API documentation states that an API key can be generated through the UI.  Where in the UI can I create an API key?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that anymore in the UI... You must use the `issue-token` command on the API to generate a token.